# Issue with size of IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, intptr

Yesterday, I posted an issue regarding passing some int** and double** from C# to C++. [How to import a C++ function with int** and double** parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221747/how-to-import-a-c-function-with-int-and-double-parameters)

Fortunately, I got some good help. Here is my new code:

```
[DllImport("opendsp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern int SetAcquisitionPointerSynchronously(int* ID, int* BufferID, out IntPtr Pointer, out IntPtr Time, int NumberOfPointers);

public unsafe int OpenDSP_SetAcquisitionPointerSynchronously(int[] IDs, int[] BufferID, ref int[] Pointer, ref double[] Time, int NumberOfPointers)
{
    IntPtr fQueue = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr fTime = IntPtr.Zero;
    int breturn = -1;
    fixed (int* fMeasurementId = IDs)
    fixed (int* fBufferID = BufferID)

    try
    {
        fQueue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)) * Pointer.Length);

        fTime = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Double)) * Time.Length);

        breturn = SetAcquisitionPointerSynchronously(fMeasurementId, fBufferID, out fQueue, out fTime, NumberOfPointers);

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double));
        for (uint i = 0; i < NumberOfPointers; i++)
            Time[i] = (double)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(fTime.ToInt32() + (size * i)), typeof(double));

        size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));
        for (uint i = 0; i < NumberOfPointers; i++)
            Pointer[i] = (int)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(fQueue.ToInt32() + (size * i)), typeof(int));

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fQueue);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fTime);
    }
    catch {
    }

    return breturn;
}
```

When my two arrays Pointer and Time are of length 2, I don't have issues. But when I increase it to 4, then my code crashes. I debugged, and it seems that when it tries to access the 4th elements of Pointer, this one points to 0x00000 so it is not accessible.

I have tried different things without success.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This code has very serious bugs and can never work as written.  The semantics of the unmanaged function are very important but are very unclear.  Pretty sure you are using it completely wrong, it wants stable pointers to memory, an array of pointers to arrays, and *not* get them de-allocated after the call.  The use of *fixed* is notable very wrong.  I strongly recommend you write a wrapper in C++/CLI instead of trying to pinvoke it.

Comment: Yes, what Hans said, with a non-trivial pinvoke is two battles, getting the code to compile is only the first, getting it to actually run correctly is a whole another ball of worms, can of wax, whatever, <insert your favorite metaphor>.

Comment: What happens when the 'fixed' statement is not "scoped" with `{}` (like it is in all examples)? Does it actually work as intended in this case?

Comment: The scope of 'fixed' is [limited to single lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663394/using-fixed-for-a-pointer-statement/8664063#8664063) (in this case). What consequence does this have?

Comment: From *[Nested 'fixed' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782992/)*: *"After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Therefore, do not point to those variables outside the 'fixed' statement."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, someone gets the same problem, I have found a solution:

C++ code:

```
int SetPointers(int* ID, int* BufferID, int** Pointer, double** Time, int NumberOfPointers);
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern Int32 SetPointers(Int32[] ID, Int32[] BufferID, IntPtr[] Pointer, IntPtr[] Time, int NumberOfPointers);
    public unsafe int SetPointers(int[] IDs, int[] BufferID, ref int[] Pointer, ref double[] Time, int NumberOfPointers)
    {
        int breturn = -1;

        IntPtr[] queue = new IntPtr[NumberOfPointers];
        IntPtr[] time = new IntPtr[NumberOfPointers];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPointers; i++)
        {
            queue[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
            time[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double)));
        }
        breturn = SetPointers(IDs, BufferID, queue, time, NumberOfPointers);

        if (breturn >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPointers; i++)
            {
                Pointer[i] = (int)Marshal.ReadInt32(queue[i]);
                Time[i] = (double)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(time[i].ToInt32()), typeof(double));
            }
        }
        return breturn;
    }
```

Comment: What is the gist of the solution? What did you change and why?